# Cannot pass a pattern to background-color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using React Javascript.

I'm trying to apply a background linear pattern to the cells of a table.
The goal is to have the cell colored for a given percentage, while the remaining is white.

The function is the following:

```
    const describeColoredSensation = (val,r,g,b,a) => {
        const pos = 10 * val;
        const def = `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a}) 0%, rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a}) ${pos}%, rgba(255,255,255,1) ${pos}%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)`
        return (
                <td 
                    style={{ background: `${def}`}} 
                >{val}</td>
        )
    };
```

The function is call as

```
<tr>                
    {describeColoredSensation(item.value,253,253,62,255)}
</tr>
```

A sample `def` variable content is:

```
"rgba(253,253,62,255) 0%, rgba(253,253,62,255) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)"
```

But inspecting the browser the background color is not set (the background-color attribte is not present).

While I have just 4 different colors, I cannot use CSS, because the value of the `val` variable changes dynamically.

BTW, if I define `const def = "rgba(255,0,0,255)";` it runs correctly, displaying all the cells in red.

Also, if I copy the content of the `def` variable in the debugger on the browser, it shows correctly.

So, I believe that the problem is how to make digest the statement to React Javascript.

Comment: Where is `describeColoredSensation` being called and what values are passed to it?

Comment: try `backgroundColor`  instead of background. `style={{ backgroundColor: `${def}`}}`

Comment: using `style={{ backgroundColor: ${def}}}` return exactly the same as using `background`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `background` takes only a single color. You should use a gradient if you want to mix colors.

*Note, while the rgb color channels are in the range `[0,255]`, the alpha channel is only in the range `[0,1]`.*

```
const describeColoredSensation = (val, r, g, b, a) => {
  const pos = 10 * val;
  const def = `linear-gradient(to right, rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a}) 0%, rgba(${r},${g},${b},${a}) ${pos}%, rgba(255,255,255,1) ${pos}%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%)`;
  return <td style={{ background: def }}>{val}</td>;
};
```

[image: Edit cannot-pass-a-pattern-to-background-color]

[image]